# SLParallaxController implementation into project with Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I wanted to implement [SLParallaxController](https://github.com/stefanlage/SLParallaxController) as main ViewController into my existing project, which has a Storyboard. With the SLParallaxController however, the content is created dynamically:

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
      // Override point for customization after application launch.
      self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

      if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
          self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
          self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
          self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
      }

      self.window.rootViewController = [SLParallaxController new];

      return YES;
  }
```

Since didFinishLaunchingWithOptions should not be used at all in a Storyboard based project I would like to implement this the proper way.

I have tried loadview, but that returned a black screen:

```
  -(void)loadView
  {
      UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
      window.rootViewController = [SLParallaxController new];
  }
```

There any alternative to implement SLParallaxController besides rebuilding the objects in the Storyboard?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post.
To give an answer I think the easiest way is to put your main ViewController inherited from SLParallaxController instead of UIViewController.

SLParallaxController implement **initWithCoder:**  so it should work using a Storyboard.

Hope this helps!